# Problema con el red de un servidor DNS con Bind9 en Linux Mint

Tags: linux, dns, redes, networking, linux-mint

Buenas tardes estoy configurando el archivo /etc/network/interface para unos ejercicios y me piden trabajar sobre la ip 192.168.200.250, pero cuando lo configuro con esos datos pierdo la conexión externa, pero si configuro por ejemplo 192.168.1.250, todo va bien, os dejo las dos configuraciones.

```
# Configuración con 192.168.1.250

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp9s0
iface enp9s0 inet static
  # Dirección estática
  address 192.168.1.250
  # Mascara de subred
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  # Red a la que pertenece la dirección IP
  network 192.168.1.0
  # IP de difusión de la red
  broadcast 192.168.200.255
  # Puerta de enlace predeterminada
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  # Direccion IP de los servidores de nombre
  dns-nameservers 192.168.1.250
  # dns-search


# Configuración con 192.168.200.250

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp9s0
iface enp9s0 inet static
  # Dirección estática
  address 192.168.200.250
  # Mascara de subred
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  # Red a la que pertenece la dirección IP
  network 192.168.200.0
  # IP de difusión de la red
  broadcast 192.168.200.255
  # Puerta de enlace predeterminada
  gateway 192.168.200.1
  # Direccion IP de los servidores de nombre
  dns-nameservers 192.168.200.250
  # dns-search
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu configuración sintacticamente y logicamente ( des de el punto de vista de host) tiene sentido.

Pierdes la conexión  a Internet porque tu `LAN` no hay nadie con ip `192.168.200.1` que te pueda servir para salir al mundo IP exterior.

Tu configuración LAN lógicamente no es correcta.

La comanda ping te puede servir para diagnosticar que esta pasando.

1. ping al GW `ping 192.168.200.1
2. ping a alguna ip publica de inet conocida globalmente como `1.1.1.1` o `9.9.9.9` `ping 1.1.1.1`

Si en `1` no hay perdidas, certificas que estas hablando con el `GW` sin problema